# SQL Subquery Question in MySQL. Subquery in WHERE, SELECT or FROM?

Tags: mysql, subquery

I am trying to solve this question from HackerRank using a subquery.

What did I do wrong?

> Query the two cities in STATION with the shortest and longest CITY names, as well as their respective lengths (i.e.: number of characters in the name). If there is more than one smallest or largest city, choose the one that comes first when ordered alphabetically.
>
> For example, CITY has four entries: DEF, ABC, PQRS and WXY.
>
> Sample output
>
> ```
> ABC  3
> PQRS 4
> ```
>
> Explanation
>
> When ordered alphabetically, the CITY names are listed as ABC, DEF, PQRS, and WXY, with lengths 3 and 4. The longest name is PQRS, but there are options for shortest named city. Choose ABC, because it comes first alphabetically.

```
SELECT 
    CITY, 
    LENGTH(SELECT MAX(CITY)
           FROM STATION) AS Length
FROM STATION
ROWNUM 1;

SELECT 
    CITY, LENGTH(SELECT MIN(CITY)
                 FROM STATION) AS Length
FROM STATION
ROWNUM 1;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can UNION the first and the last

> ```
> CREATE tABLE A (city varchar(10))
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO A VALUES ('DEF'),('ABC'), ('PQRS'), ('WXY')
> ```

> ```
> (SELECT city
> , LENGTH(city)
> FROM A
> ORDER BY LENGTH(city) ASC,city LIMIT 1)
> UNION ALL
> (SELECT city
> , LENGTH(city)
> FROM A
> ORDER BY LENGTH(city) DESC,city LIMIT 1)
> ```
>
> ```
> city | LENGTH(city)
> :--- | -----------:
> ABC  |            3
> PQRS |            4
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=19ca4c54eb2bbceecf5d8ac32c801099)*

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT Top 1  CITY, LEN(CITY) AS city_length
FROM STATION
WHERE LEN(CITY) = (
    SELECT MIN(LEN(CITY))
    FROM STATION 
) ORDER BY CITY 
SELECT Top 1  CITY, LEN(CITY) AS city_length
FROM STATION
WHERE LEN(CITY) = (
    SELECT Max(LEN(CITY))
    FROM STATION 
) ORDER BY CITY
```